# Sum n values in numpy array based on pandas index

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to calculate the cumulative sum of the first n values in a numpy array, where n is a value in each row of a pandas dataframe. I have set up a little example problem with a single column and it works fine, but it does not work when I have more than one column.

## Example problem that fails:

```
a=np.ones((10,))
df=pd.DataFrame([[4.,2],[6.,1],[5.,2.]],columns=['nj','ni'])
df['nj']=df['nj'].astype(int)
df['nsum']=df.apply(lambda x: np.sum(a[:x['nj']]),axis=1)
df
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_23612/1905114001.py in <module>
      2 df=pd.DataFrame([[4.,2],[6.,1],[5.,2.]],columns=['nj','ni'])
      3 df['nj']=df['nj'].astype(int)
----> 4 df['nsum']=df.apply(lambda x: np.sum(a[:x['nj']]),axis=1)
      5 df

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7766             kwds=kwds,
   7767         )
-> 7768         return op.get_result()
   7769 
   7770     def applymap(self, func, na_action: Optional[str] = None) -> DataFrame:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    183             return self.apply_raw()
    184 
--> 185         return self.apply_standard()
    186 
    187     def apply_empty_result(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    274 
    275     def apply_standard(self):
--> 276         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    277 
    278         # wrap results

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    288             for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    289                 # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 290                 results[i] = self.f(v)
    291                 if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    292                     # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_23612/1905114001.py in <lambda>(x)
      2 df=pd.DataFrame([[4.,2],[6.,1],[5.,2.]],columns=['nj','ni'])
      3 df['nj']=df['nj'].astype(int)
----> 4 df['nsum']=df.apply(lambda x: np.sum(a[:x['nj']]),axis=1)
      5 df

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

## Example problem that works:

```
a=np.ones((10,))
df=pd.DataFrame([4.,6.,5.],columns=['nj'])
df['nj']=df['nj'].astype(int)
df['nsum']=df.apply(lambda x: np.sum(a[:x['nj']]),axis=1)
df
    nj  nsum
0   4   4.0
1   6   6.0
2   5   5.0
```

In both cases:

```
print(a.shape)
print(a.dtype)
print(type(df))
print(df['nj'].dtype)

(10,)
float64
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
int32
```

A work around that is not very satisfying, especially because I would eventually like to use multiple columns in the lambda function, is:

```
tmp=pd.DataFrame(df['nj'])
df['nsum'] = tmp.apply(lambda x: np.sum(delr[:x['nj']]),axis=1)
```

Any clarification on what I have missed here or better work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do it in numpy with [`numpy.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) and [`numpy.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
np.take(np.cumsum(a, axis=0), df['nj'], axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to figure out why/if take is better than just: np.cumsum(a)[df['nj']]

Comment: Well, as we don't really know what is your use case, it is difficult to know. Please provide the expected output and details on what you really want to achieve

Comment: The "example problem that works" in the original post has the desired output. The method you provided is one increment higher, but that is expected and easily fixed. But as far as I can tell np.cumsum(a)[df['nj']] gives the same answer as your method, so I'm curious what the benefit of np.take is, over just indexing the cumsum.

Comment: Maybe I didn't fully understand what you want to do. If it works as you want without `take`, then remove it. Your example was a bit ambiguous as your array was ones only. Maybe provide a less ambiguous example? Or better something like [[a,b,c], [d,e,f]] and the detail of the calculations you expect.

Answer (score 0):

A small adjustment to pass just the column of interest (df['nj']) to lambda solved my initial issue:

```
df['nsum'] = df['nj'].apply(lambda x: np.sum(a[:x]))
```

Using mozway's suggestion of np.take and np.cumsum along with a less ambiguous(?) example, the following will also work (but note the x-1 since the initial problem states "the cumulative sum of the first n values" rather than the cumulative sum to index n):

```
a=np.array([3,2,4,5,1,2,3])
df=pd.DataFrame([[4.,2],[6.,1],[5.,3.]],columns=['nj','ni'])
df['nj']=df['nj'].astype(int)
df[['nsumj']]=df['nj'].apply(lambda x: np.take(np.cumsum(a),x-1))
#equivalent?
# df[['nsumj']]=df['nj'].apply(lambda x: np.cumsum(a)[x-1])
print(a)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
[3 2 4 5 1 2 3]
   nj   ni  nsumj
0   4  2.0     14
1   6  1.0     17
2   5  3.0     15
```

From the example [here](https://codeforests.medium.com/ppicpandas-tricks-pass-multiple-columns-to-lambda-e0c16312fb50) it seems the key to using multiple columns in the funtion (the next issue I was running into and hinted at) is to unpack the columns, so I will put this here incase it helps anyone:

```
df['nprod']=df[['ni','nj']].apply(lambda x: np.multiply(*x),axis=1)
```